# How to use typescript interfaces in angular2 forms?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a simple form in angular2 where the object which i pass to create the form should be of interface type...I have made a small plunker demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/GXyZfXenDcDLiCWwjfYN?p=preview ...If the object passed is of type null then i want to call new instance but it is not happening... Is it possible to call new instance for interface...

```
interface  Cust {
label: string;
}
```

This is my interface and below is how i am calling new instance in my component

```
  Create(data:Cust){
if(data==null){
  data=new Cust();
}
    this.myForm = this.localfb.group({  
  'sku':  [data.label, Validators.required]  
}); 
}
```

Somebody please guide me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate an interface. You want a class, not an interface. If you look at the JavaScript output, you'll see that an interface doesn't actually create any output, while a closure is created for a class.

Comment: Thanks @rgvassar...yea i have implemented using class...Thanks